# Is this one of them circular references?

Tags: c#, httpcontext, helper, circular-reference

I want to add an easily accessible helper class to my *asp mvc* page. I created a class called *Repositories*. It has a static property "Current" which does the following:

```
public static readonly Repositories Current
{
    get
    {
        if(HttpContext.Current.Items["Repositories"] == null)
            HttpContext.Current.Items["Repositories"] = new Repositories(HttpContext.Current);
        return (Repositories)HttpContext.Current.Items["Repositories"];
    }
}
```

The point is that the class has static helper functions that use the current instance of the class (tied to current *httpcontext*). The helper functions do all kinds of stuff, the reason I wanted to organize them like this is because it makes for a nicer looking code in the controllers and i have potential access to all database repositories (the actual handle objects are created only if accessed in this context though).

Anyway, as you can see, the constructor takes a *HttpContext* as an argument, which is then stored in a private class field so I'd have less to type. This means that the Repositories class instance refers to *HttpContext* class instance and vice-versa. When the *HttpContext* is dropped, does this mean that it still sticks around in the memory, being preserved by a circular-reference by the *Repositories* instance?

Comment: When do you expect the HttpContext to be dropped?

Comment: Aside from your question, what you're doing here is just introducing _global variables_.
I would strongly avoid such a design if I were you : it will lead to untestable code.
You should inject your repositories in your controllers thru the constructor rather than using the HttpContext to retrieve them.

Comment: Its not really global though if the helper class is instanced per each request or is it? I tried doing the whole injection thing but its just so clunky, i dont likey.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong: constructor injection in ASP.NET MVC through frameworks like Ninject of Unity (and their MVC extensions) is really straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

An "orphaned" circular reference doesn't force objects to stay around in memory.

If you do this:

```
class A
{
    public B b;

    ~A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("COLLECTED A!");
    }
}

class B
{
    public A a;

    ~B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("COLLECTED B!");
    }
}
```

and run this code:

```
var a = new A();
var b = new B();

a.b = b;
b.a = a;

a = null;
b = null;

GC.Collect();
```

Both instances can (and will) be garbage collected. You will get something similar to the following output:

```
COLLECTED B!
COLLECTED A!
```